# Upload and read the excel file and insert the data in Database using groovy grails

Tags: excel, grails, groovy

Here is the GSP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <title>Upload New Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul><li><g:link class="list" action="list">Document List</g:link></li></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="content scaffold-create" role="main">
                <h1>Upload New Document</h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}"><div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div></g:if>
            <g:uploadForm action="upload">
                    <fieldset class="form">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset class="buttons">
                            <g:submitButton name="upload" class="save" value="Upload" />
                    </fieldset>
            </g:uploadForm>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the  Controller:

```
def upload() {

        def file = request.getFile('file')

        // inp = new FileInputStream(uploadedFile);

        XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet[] sheets = book.sheets;
        for (XSSFSheet sheet : sheets)
        {
            println("\nSHEET NAME:"+sheet.getSheetName()+"\n");
            sheet.each { row ->
                Iterator cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    XSSFCell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    print(getCellValue(cell)+" ");
                }
                println();
            }
        }
        if(file.empty) {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        } else {
            def documentInstance = new Document()
            documentInstance.filename = file.originalFilename
            documentInstance.filedata = file.getBytes()
            documentInstance.save()
        }
        redirect (action:'list')
    }
```

I am getting the spring based exception

```
Could not find matching constructor for: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook(org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile)
```

Comment: change it to `new XSSFWorkbook(file.inputStream)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor for `XSSFWorkbook` requires an `InputStream`. So the constructor should look like this:

```
XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(file.getInputStream());
```

You can look at the related API docs for both [XSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook%28java.io.InputStream%29) and [CommonsMultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks its working.Next step to insert the excel data into the mongodb using groovy grails.Please let me know

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a [`CommonsMultipartFile`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartFile.html) to the constructor of [`XSSFWorkbook`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html)

Instead, pass an `InputStream`:

```
    XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook( file.inputStream )
```

Comment: Next step to insert the excel data into the mongodb using groovy grails.Please let me know.